# When the instantiation is possible but iheritance is not in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, decorator, instantiation

In C++ Decorator Software Design Pattern is appropriate to use when you have a type, which can be instantiated but there is a restriction that don't let you to inherit from that class in order to add some functionality.

My question is: what are the cases in C++ that I can have an instance of a class but cannot inherit from the same class?

Comment: Any class that has a `private` constructor and a static factory method.

Comment: For example a class with a private constructor.

Comment: this should be the same as for `final` in java. Its a security and performance thing. If you allow (others) to inherit/subclass your code, then you either have to really carefully take care about protected/private methods that need to be the way they are... or dont let them inherit yours. Edit: did you other guys even read his question? he did not ask how to do that ;-)

Comment: @Najzero It’s not a security thing. Neither C++ nor Java prevent runtime circumvention of the mechanism.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: so in Java, how do I circumvent the `final` mechanism in order to do the most obviously-useful exploit, which is to pass my own subclass of `String` into security manager code that relies on that instance not changing while it is being tested for validity? My knowledge may be well out of date, but I thought the final-ness and immutability of `java.lang.String` *can* be relied on even in a JVM that has loaded untrusted bytecode.

Comment: @Steve Exactly: security is implemented by signing code and using the security manager, not by `final` itself.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: what do you mean, "exactly"?. I asked you how to do it, because I was not aware that it can be done. Further, how does the JVM enforce the sandbox for untrusted bytecode, if it can't enforce `final` on `java.lang.String` and hence security manager code cannot assume that user-supplied strings are immutable?

Comment: @Steve It can be done by disabling the security manager, and more generally you can only rely on trusted bytecode being untampered with, not untrusted one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK, so you're saying that it's only the security manager that enforces `final`, not the language rules followed by the classloader? I never realised that. I think that back in the day, the Java implementation I worked on didn't behave as you would expect, since I'm pretty sure we did enforce `final` in the classloader. Whether the bytecode was trusted or not, we simply wouldn't load a class that tried to inherit from `String`. I just didn't know that was implementation-specific behaviour...

Comment: @Steve Yes. Essentially what I’m saying is that in normal untrusted bytecode `final` or `private` do *not* provide security since they can be circumvented, for instance by reflection.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I think I'll make a new question of this, unless you can save me the trouble. Do you happen to know of some article or documentation showing in detail how to inherit from `java.lang.String`?

Comment: @Steve Well `java.lang.String` *is* trusted code. I don’t think you can simply inherit from it. I may be mistaken though, I never had to care about the intricacies of the JRE’s security.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK, I took the statement "Java does not prevent circumvention of this mechanism" to mean, "Java never prevents you inheriting from any `final` class". `java.lang.String` is a particularly important example of a final class. It's possible we've been talking entirely at cross purposes. If all you meant is that Java lets you inherit one user-defined class from another `final` user-defined class, then I'm less excited about it, although I'm still slightly surprised :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick you can use in C++03 to avoid needing a factory:

```
struct Final;

struct FinalHelper {
    friend struct Final;
  private:
    FinalHelper() {}
    ~FinalHelper() {}
};

struct Final : private virtual FinalHelper {
    Final() {}
};
```

This doesn't actually prevent someone from using `Final` as a base class, but it does prevent them from constructing or destroying their derived class. The reason is that the most-derived class is responsible for constructing and destroying virtual bases, but the constructor and destructor of `FinalHelper` are not accessible in the most-derived class unless it is `Final`.

Of course this probably has a runtime memory cost (for the virtual base).

Usually such tricks are pointless. C++ relies on programmers reading the documentation, so a built-in `final` mechanism is fine, but you don't want to incur either a runtime cost (for the virtual base) or a usability cost (for the factory function, since the type can only be copy-constructed, which for example affects its use with some container member functions) just to enforce documentation.

So, types should document whether or not they are intended for use as base classes, and users who ignore that documentation only have themselves to blame.

Answer (score 5):

If your C++ compiler is C++11 compatible, you can declare the class to be [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) to make a class non-inheritable:

```
class A final
{
};
```

---

If you don't have access to a compiler supporting the `final` keyword, then you have to make the constructor private and use a static factory method:

```
class A
{
    A() {}

public:
    A createA() { return A(); }
};
```

Comment: In general, aside of `final` please...

Comment: @Narek Then a private constructor and a static factory function as suggested by Jon.

Comment: Sometimes people say that you can't inherit from the class if you are not the "owner". What does it mean?

Comment: @Narek You'd have to ask them what they mean, that doesn't make sense to me.